# Python PCA Implementation

Tags: python, pca

I'm working on an assignment where I am tasked to implement PCA in Python for an online course.  Unfortunately, when I try to run a comparison (provided by the course) between my implementation and SKLearn's, my results appear to differ too greatly.

After many hours of review, I am still unsure where it is going wrong.  If someone could take a look and determine what step I have coded or interpreted incorrectly, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
def normalize(X):
    """
    Normalize the given dataset X to have zero mean.

    Args:
        X: ndarray, dataset of shape (N,D)
    Returns:
        (Xbar, mean): tuple of ndarray, Xbar is the normalized dataset
        with mean 0; mean is the sample mean of the dataset.

    Note: 
        You will encounter dimensions where the standard deviation is zero.

        For those ones, the process of normalization results in normalized data with NaN entries.  

        We can handle this by setting the std = 1 for those dimensions when doing normalization.  
    """
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    ### Uncomment and modify the code below
    mu = np.mean(X, axis = 0) # Setting axis = 0 will compute means column-wise.  Setting it to 1 will compute the mean across rows.  
    std = np.std(X, axis = 0) # Computing the std dev column wise using axis = 0.  
    std_filled = std.copy() 
    std_filled[std == 0] = 1
    # Compute the normalized data as Xbar 
    Xbar = (X - mu)/std_filled
    return Xbar, mu, # std_filled

def eig(S):
    """
    Compute the eigenvalues and corresponding unit eigenvectors for the covariance matrix S.

    Args:
        S: ndarray, covariance matrix

    Returns:
        (eigvals, eigvecs): ndarray, the eigenvalues and eigenvectors

    Note:
        the eigenvals and eigenvecs should be sorted in descending
        order of the eigen values
    """
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    # Uncomment and modify the code below
    # Compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
    # You can use library routines in `np.linalg.*` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.linalg.html for this
    eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eig(S)
    # The eigenvalues and eigenvectors need to be sorted in descending order according to the eigenvalues
    # We will use `np.argsort` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to find a permutation of the indices
    # of eigvals that will sort eigvals in ascending order and then find the descending order via [::-1], which reverse the indices
    sort_indices = np.argsort(eigvals)[::-1]
    # Notice that we are sorting the columns (not rows) of eigvecs since the columns represent the eigenvectors.
    return eigvals[sort_indices], eigvecs[:, sort_indices]


def projection_matrix(B):
    """Compute the projection matrix onto the space spanned by the columns of `B`
    Args:
        B: ndarray of dimension (D, M), the basis for the subspace

    Returns:
        P: the projection matrix
    """
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    P = B @ (np.linalg.inv(B.T @ B)) @ B.T
    return P

def select_components(eig_vals, eig_vecs, num_components):
    """ 
    Selects the n components desired for projecting the data upon.  

    Args:
        eig_vals: The eigenvalues sorted in descending order of magnitude. 
        eig_vecs:  The eigenvectors sorted in order relative to that of the eigenvalues.
        num_components: the number of principal components to use.  
    Returns: 
        The number of desired components to keep for projection of the data upon. 
    """
    principal_vals, principal_components = eig_vals[:num_components], eig_vecs[:, range(num_components)]

    return principal_vals, principal_components


def PCA(X, num_components):
    """
    Projects normalized data onto the 'n' desired principal components.

    Args:
        X: ndarray of size (N, D), where D is the dimension of the data,
        and N is the number of datapoints
        num_components: the number of principal components to use.
    Returns:
        the reconstructed data, the sample mean of the X, principal values
        and principal components
    """
    # Normalize to have mean 0 and variance 1.
    Z, mean_vec = normalize(X) 
    # Calculate the covariance matrix 
    S = np.cov(Z, rowvar=False, bias=True) # Set rowvar = False to treat columns as variables.  Set bias = True to ensure normalization is done with N and not N-1
    # Calculate the (unit) eigenvectors and eigenvalues of S.  Sort them in descending order of importance relative to the magnitude of the eigenvalues.  
    eig_vals, eig_vecs = eig(S)
    # Keep only the n largest Principle Components of the sorted unit eigenvectors.
    principal_vals, principal_components = select_components(eig_vals, eig_vecs, num_components)
    # Compute the projection matrix using only the n largest Principle Components of the sorted unit eigenvectors, where n = num_components.  
    #P = projection_matrix(eig_vecs[:, :num_components])
    P = projection_matrix(principal_components)
    # Reconstruct the data by using the projection matrix to project the data onto the principal component vectors we've kept
    X_reconst = (P @ X.T).T 

    return X_reconst, mean_vec, principal_vals, principal_components
```

And here is the test case I'm supposed to pass:

```
random = np.random.RandomState(0)
X = random.randn(10, 5)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as SKPCA

for num_component in range(1, 4):
    # We can compute a standard solution given by scikit-learn's implementation of PCA
    pca = SKPCA(n_components=num_component, svd_solver="full")
    sklearn_reconst = pca.inverse_transform(pca.fit_transform(X))
    reconst, _, _, _ = PCA(X, num_component)
    # The difference in the result should be very small (<10^-20)
    print(
        "difference in reconstruction for num_components = {}: {}".format(
            num_component, np.square(reconst - sklearn_reconst).sum()
        )
    )
    np.testing.assert_allclose(reconst, sklearn_reconst)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there are a few things wrong with your code.

Your projection matrix is wrong.

If the eigenvectors of your covariance matrix is B with dimension D x M where M is the number of components you select and D is the dimension of the original data, then the projection matrix is just `B @ B.T`.

In standard implementation of PCA, we typically do not scale the data by the inverse of the standard deviation. You seem to be trying to do an approximation of a whitened PCA (ZCA), but even then it looks wrong.

As a quick test, you can compute the normalized data without dividing by the standard deviation, and when you compute the covariance matrix, set `bias=False`.

You should also subtract the mean from the data before multiplying it by the projection operator, and adding it back after that, i.e.,
`X_reconst = (P @ (X - mean_vec).T).T + mean_vec`.

PCA essentially is just a change of basis, followed by discarding coordinates corresponding to directions with low variance. The eigenvectors of the covariance matrix corresponds to the new orthogonal basis, and the eigenvalues tells you the variance of the data along the direction of the corresponding eigenvectors. P = B @ B.T is just the change of basis followed to the new basis (and discarding some coordinates), B, followed by a change back to the original basis.

#### Edit

I'm curious to know which online course teaches people to implement PCA this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
X_reconst = (P @ Z.T).T + mean_vec
```

You need add the mean of X back.